# How can alter an Event in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have have a scheduled event that I would like to alter. I normally like to use the MySql workbench but it does not show the information_schema to edit events. I am trying to use phpMyAdmin to alter the event but I just cant figure it out.

I would just like to update the event_definition from:

```
UPDATE USER SET USER.account_status=false WHERE USER.account_status = true AND USER.lastupdate < (NOW() - INTERVAL 2880 MINUTE)
```

To

```
UPDATE USER SET USER.account_status=false WHERE USER.account_status = true AND USER.lastupdate < (NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)
```

The event name is `StatusSet`

Normally I am asking java questions so please excuse me if I have left out important information for you to give me an answer. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I tried creating a new event in phpMyAdmin and I am getting a #1044 Access is denied error.

Comment: To view the information_schema in Workbench, enable to "Show Metadata and Internal Schemas" Workbench preference.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you could check your privileges by running `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;`

I would ask whether you are using the proper `ALTER EVENT` [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-event.html), but the error message is on creating the event, so you should definitely check the user's privileges especially if they are IP related (user@ip).